Getting DATATYPE_MISMATCH.UNEXPECTED_INPUT_TYPE while working on a project in Databricks using Apache Spark
I am working on a project in Databricks using Apache Spark,
I was doing some data manipulation, during which I encountered this error basically stating "DATATYPE_MISMATCH.UNEXPECTED_INPUT_TYPE".
The code snippet is as follows:
player_match_df = player_match_df.withColumn(
    "years_since_debut",
    (year(current_date()) - (col("season_year")))
)

More details:

Cannot resolve "(year(current_date()) - season_year)" due to data type mismatch: parameter 1 requires "DATE" type, however, "year(current_date())" is of "INT" type.;

Resolve the error without changing much structure.

Please provide the schema of player_match_df - specifically for the season_year column - with some sample values to make it easier for people to help you with this question. Please read on [mre].
